# Relationship between the zeros and coefficients of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am learning about polynomials currently. I stumbled upon a topic in my book where it explains the **relationship between the coefficients of a quadratic polynomial and it's zeros**. I got confused in one of the step showcased in the book.

In line 3 of the [snapshot from my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZQUq.jpg), it is written

> Then, (x-alpha) and (x-beta) are the factors of p(x)

But it doesn't explains how.

I tried to get my head into it but I couldn't get to a satisfactorys answer about how is that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: **Hint :** Prove that for any polynomial $P$, if $P(\alpha)=0$, then there exists a polynomial $Q$ such that $P(X)=(X-\alpha)Q(X)$.